# How to not make PHPmailer send an email with multiple 'to' addresses?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a table in my database which contains emails to be sent. A script runs periodically as a cron job to read the data from table and dispatch the emails via the SMTP server. I am using PHPMailer for the work here. The script runs a loop for sending emails until all the emails in the table have been sent.

The problem is that most consecutive emails being sent have a common subject. So when the loop runs, somehow all the emails that get sent have a long 'to' list. So basically if 5 email entries (with different **to** addresses) have the same subject and same content, then it ends up sending only 1 email with 5 addresses (one of each email entry) in the 'to' field. This reveals the email address of every person to everyone else on the list. This is undesirable and the emails must be sent to only that one person for whom it is meant.

I don't know what's at play here. Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems like you should be looping on the users and sending the emails, instead of looping on the emails and adding the users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing something like this?

```
$mailer = new PHPMailer();

while($row = fetch_from_db()) {
   $mailer->AddAddress($row['email']);
   $mailer->send();
}
```

If so, you need to do a

```
$mailer->ClearAllRecipients()
```

after you send each email, so you start out with a "fresh" `To:` list.

Comment: I was getting bugged by this. Thanks for the help, it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row = fetch_from_db()) {
   $mailer->AddAddress($row['email']);
   $mailer->send();
   $mailer->ClearAllRecipients()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1st, get the contacts from your db

```
$contacts = 'GET CONTACTS ARRAY FROM DB'
        if(!empty($contacts)){
            foreach ($contacts as $crt_contact){
               $emails[] = $crt_contact->email ;
            }
        }
```

2nd use the following to create the "to" field

```
$to = implode(',', array_unique($emails));
```

Use the `$to` to send in mail() function

Comment: That is a noble idea but what I am trying to do is to send individual emails to people, no one email to several people. I guess, what I can do is to use one 'to' address and the rest can be sent to 'bcc'. Let me see.